# for loop math with array in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to practice using Arrays methods in java. I used the following code to make an Java array:

```
int numArr[] = new int[10];

for(int i = 0; i< numArr.length;++i)
{
    numArr[(numArr.length)-i-1] = (i+1)*2;
    System.out.println("numArr[i]" + numArr[i]);
}
```

My intention was to use this to make the list 20,18,...,4,2. Then, I wanted to use the Arrays sort method to see if it worked properly.

The odd result that I can't understand is that above code prints:

```
numArr[i] = 0;
numArr[i] = 0;
numArr[i] = 0;
numArr[i] = 0;
numArr[i] = 0;
numArr[i] = 10;
numArr[i] = 8;
numArr[i] = 6;
numArr[i] = 4;
numArr[i] = 2;
```

I understand the simple mistake with printing the i each time but I don't understand why the initial results are all the 0. I thought maybe it just failed and they were still just initialized to the 0 default. But then I realized that after later in the code after using Arrays.sort(), the list prints correctly for all of the indexes 2,4,...,18,20.

What mistake am I making on the pre-sorted array print?

Comment: You set `numArr[(numArr.length)-i-1]`, so why are you printing `numArr[i]`?

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40755381/edit) button under your post to edit.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you learn to use a debugger.  If you had used a debugger here, it would have told you almost immediately what was wrong.  And using a debugger will save you literally months of your life, if you ever become a professional programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in how you are indexing into the array in the loop. You are assigning to array element `(numArr.length)-i-1` but printing array element `i`. Try printing array element `(numArr.length)-i-1` inside the loop to see the value you just assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print the results even before they are populated in the array.
Here you are populating from behind but trying to print from front(Which are not yet given any value)

Wait for the array to get populated and loop through the array to get the proper result

Doing this should solve your problem,

```
for(int i = 0; i< numArr.length;++i)
{
    numArr[(numArr.length)-i-1] = (i+1)*2;

}
for(int i = numArr.length-1; i>-1;i--)
{
    System.out.println(numArr[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `i=0`, or the first loop.

```
numArr[(numArr.length)-i-1] = (i+1)*2;
```

Run that through, you get

```
numArr[9] = 2;
```

Yet, you print `numArr[0]`, which is not yet assigned.

You'll start seeing values once you reach the midpoint of the array

---

If you are still confused, write out your algorithm on paper

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print indexes which has their default value (0) in it. Instead, try printing the indexes which you've already assigned a value into

```
for(int i = 0; i< numArr.length;++i)
{
    numArr[i] = (i+1)*2;
    System.out.println("numArr[i]" + numArr[i]);
}
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i< numArr.length;++i)
{
    numArr[(numArr.length)-i-1] = (i+1)*2;
    System.out.println("numArr[i]" + numArr[(numArr.length)-i-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Vinay pointed out when printing you are using i as subscript for array elements that didn't get populated yet. If you want to print array while populated you have to use the same index

```
int numArr[] = new int[10];

for(int i = 0; i< numArr.length;++i)
{
    numArr[(numArr.length)-i-1] = (i+1)*2;
    System.out.println("numArr[(numArr.length)-i-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is populate the array and then print the result with another loop:

### Test:

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        int numArr[] = new int[10];

        for(int i = 0; i< numArr.length;++i)
        {
            numArr[(numArr.length)-i-1] = (i+1)*2;

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("numArr["+i+"]" + numArr[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

### Output:

```
numArr[0]20
numArr[1]18
numArr[2]16
numArr[3]14
numArr[4]12
numArr[5]10
numArr[6]8
numArr[7]6
numArr[8]4
numArr[9]2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int numArr[] = new int[10];

for(int i = numArr.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    numArr[i] = (i+1)*2;
    System.out.println("numArr["+i+"]" + numArr[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
numArr[9]20
numArr[8]18
numArr[7]16
numArr[6]14
numArr[5]12
numArr[4]10
numArr[3]8
numArr[2]6
numArr[1]4
numArr[0]2
```

Is this what you wanted to look like?

[Vote up if helped]